# ActiveRecord: get values in right order as in :select defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a string with column names and I want to print out the keys and values in this order.

```
# controller
fields = "name, year, title"
@blas = Bla.find(23, :select=>fields)

# view
<% @blas.attributes.each do |k,v| %>
  <%=k %>:<%=v %><br>
<% end %>
```

The result I get is in this order "name, title, year" but I want "name, year, title", like I defined it in **fields**.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cycle through them like this:

```
# controller
@fields = "name, year, title"
@blas = Bla.find(23, :select=>@fields)

# view
<% @fields.split(',').map(&:strip).each do |key| %>
  <%= k %>:<%= @blas[k] %><br />
<% end %>
```